# How to have a map with two keys? c++

Tags: c++, dictionary, std-pair

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main() {

    std::map<std::pair<int, int>, std::string> mymap;
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i = i + 2) {
        std::pair<int, int> temp;
        temp.first = i;
        temp.second = i+1;
        std::string temp2;
        std::cout << "Enter a string: ";
        std::cin >> temp2;
        mymap[temp] = temp2;
    }

    while(1) {
        int temp, temp2;
        std::cout << "Enter a number: ";
        std::cin >> temp;
        std::cout << "Enter another number: ";
        std::cin >> temp2;

        std::pair<int, int> test;
        test.first = temp;
        test.second = temp2;
        std::cout << mymap[test] << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Running that code, put in 5 strings when it asks, like:

```
foo1
foo2
foo3
foo4
foo5
```

Then you should be able to enter a pair of numbers and get the string out, like `1 2` should give `foo1` but it doesn't. Any ideas how I can fix it?

Comment: simple solution: join two keys by delimiter into one key

Comment: @gaussblurinc that's not quite the answer I was looking for in this case...

Comment: "but it doesn't." What do you get instead?

Comment: Instead of `1 2`, try `0 1`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code does not get the data because you entered `1, 2` but the map does not have that pair in it, because the keys that you used in the `for` loop start at zero, i.e.

```
0 1
2 3
4 5
6 7
8 9
```

Entering any of these pairs should give you an answer from the map, which you have implemented correctly.

[Demo on ideone](http://ideone.com/VsKGEr).

Comment: XD I feel stupid now.

At least there's an example code for a two key map if someone is interested.

Answer (score 2):

It's a good idea for you to learn how to diagnose problems. You could have identified your problem by yourself by printing the contents of the map.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main() {

    std::map<std::pair<int, int>, std::string> mymap;
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i = i + 2) {
        std::pair<int, int> temp;
        temp.first = i;
        temp.second = i+1;
        std::string temp2;
        std::cout << "Enter a string: ";
        std::cin >> temp2;
        mymap[temp] = temp2;
    }

    std::map<std::pair<int, int>, std::string>::iterator iter = mymap.begin();
    for ( ; iter != mymap.end(); ++iter )
    {
      std::cout
       << "Key: (" << iter->first.first << ", " << iter->first.second << "), Value: "
       << iter->second << std::endl;
    }

    while(1) {
        int temp, temp2;
        std::cout << "Enter a number: ";
        std::cin >> temp;
        std::cout << "Enter another number: ";
        std::cin >> temp2;

        std::pair<int, int> test;
        test.first = temp;
        test.second = temp2;
        std::cout << mymap[test] << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ah, I did not know there were iterators for maps. That *is* useful to know. Thank you.